# Как использовать 1 адаптер для 5 фрагментов?

Tags: java, android, adapter, fragmentpageradapter

У меня есть адаптер, который рисует строку и картинку. Этот адаптер используют сейчас 5 фрагментов.

Я где-то читал, что адаптер не должен быть привязан к классу. Адаптер должен нести в своем названии лишь то, что он делает.

Поэтому, думаю неправильно будет создавать для каждого фрагмента или активити свой адаптер. (Если я не прав, то поправьте меня).

Но, вся моя проблема в том, что в адаптере все взаимодействия используются в `BindView`, а точнее, имею ввиду `OnClickListener`.

Получается 1 фрагмент использует адаптер и по нажатию происходит одно. 2 фрагмент делает другое, 3 - третье и т.д.

Единственный вариант: передавать в адаптер некую Integer переменную и делать проверку. Но, согласитесь, что это выглядит как-то не профессионально. Если вы помните, то раньше в `ListView` была возможность вынести `OnItemClickListener` и все проблемы были решены. А как быть с `RecyclerView`?

---

Вот то что я понял из ваших ответов.

```
public class PhotoAlbumsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoAlbumsAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private Context context;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    private String str[] = {"test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test"};

    public PhotoAlbumsAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_album_small, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtTitle.setOnClickListener(onItemClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return str.length;
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener){
        this.onItemClickListener= onItemClickListener;
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.imgAlbum) ImageView imgAlbum;
        @BindView(R.id.txtTitle) TextView txtTitle;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onClick();
    }
}
```

`holder.txtTitle.setOnClickListener(onItemClickListener);` IDEA помечяет красным цветом. Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаем в адаптере

```
private View.OnClickListener onClickListener;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.txtTitle.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(View.OnClickListener onClickListener){
    this.onClickListener=onClickListener;
}
```

Теперь после создания экземпляра адаптера, у данного адаптера будет метод `setOnItemClickListener`. Вызываем его и внутри описываем все наши действия.

```
photoAlbumsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("GroupFragment=onClick", "TESA" + "");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно Вас понял, Вам нужно сделать кастомный callback для адаптера.

Например:

```
public interface OnItemClickListener{
   void onClick();
}
```

Далее, в адаптере посетить экземпляр данного листнера:

```
public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener:itemClickListener){
  this.itemClickListener=itemClickListener;
}
```

В методе `onBindViewHolder` в адаптере, просто вызывайте данный callback:

```
holder.tvTest.setOnClickListener(v->itemClickListener.onClick())
```

В каждом из фрагментов код будет следующим:

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

   //действие по клику
})
```

---

**UPDATE**

Вы передаёте не тот экземпляр в `onClickListener` Вашего текстового поля.
Сделайте вот так:

```
holder.txtTitle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
  onItemClickListemer.onClick()
}
```

Смысл в том, что Вы делаете собственный листнер, который срабатывает по клику на текстовое поле.

Comment: this.itemClickListener Создать в Адаптере приватный экземпляр OnItemClickListener?

Comment: Да, всё верно. Приватный экземпляр и сеттер к нему

Comment: `holder.txtTitle.setOnClickListener(onItemClickListener);`

setOnClickListener
(android.view.View.OnClickListener)
in View cannot be applied
to
(adapters.PhotoAlbumsAdapter.OnItemClickListener)

Comment: Обновите вопрос, и покажите полностью код адаптера и одного из фрагментов

Comment: Обновил вопрос посомтрите

Comment: Также не забудьте на ваш `TextView` в XML присвоить `android:clickable="true"`. И, кстати, почему бы не использовать аннотацию `@OnClick` из ButterKnife? Также советую создать метод `bind(int position)` в самом холдере и вызывайте его из `onBindViewHolder`. Так вы избавитесь от вечных обращений к вьюшкам через холдер + если холдеров будет много, то `onBindViewHolder` будет завален кодом.

Comment: По поводу ошибки `cannot be applied to` вы передаёт в `setOnClickListener` вашего `TextView` не тот интерфейс. Вам вообще на что нужно ставить слушатель? Только на `TextView`?

Comment: Обновил ответ. @Flippy все верно написал

Comment: no news. Не предлагайте больше ответы никому, Я понять не могу вы когда код даете людям вы вообще в Среде проверяете его? Ваш код даже на этапе компиляции не проходит.

Comment: @EraNewGames Всё что Вам нужно сделать, это посетить листенер в кнопку, и в нём сделать вызов необходимого каллбэка. И всё у Вас заработает.
На какую строку у Вас ругается? где информация?

Comment: У View нету OnItemClickListener. У них есть OnClickListener. Не путайте такие вещи. Людей в заблуждения бросает такие интерфейсы

Comment: onItemClickListemer это ваш собственный каллбэк. Естественно у View его нет, но никто Вам не запрещает вызывать сторонние листнеры. У меня данный код прекрасно работает.

Comment: и перед тем как бросаться на людей и показывать свои амбиции, писать про то, что кто-то путает базовые вещи, спрашивайте, если что-то не понимаете. Тут люди не первый год работают.

Comment: Я человек простой. Если инфа 100% то я делюсь со всеми, если она не достовернная или нет времени проверить ее я не афиширую данную информацию.

А вам по всей видимости все равно. Любите вы людей в заблуждения вводить, удовольствие получаете с этого что ли.

Comment: @EraNewGames перед тем как писать данное решение, я проверил его в среде разработки, у меня все было хорошо. Видимо Вы что-то неправильно делали, и Вам гораздо выгоднее переложить вину на других людей.

В любом случае, я рад, что Вы разобрались, можем закончить данный разговор. Удачи